# python list and python error to execute

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

i want to create a python script to take input some list (float or integer) and that list get in my progress and i take some new list with the new values(from the progress).

my code :

```
    for i in (mylist):
        if i==1:
                result=1
        elif (i>1) and (i<2):
                result=2
        elif i==3:
                result=3
    .........................
    a.append(result)
print(a)
```

if i execute that code i take only one value result(i thing so the first value) i want for all values in my first list

if i change the code to :

```
for i in (mylist):
    if mylist[i]==1:
            result=1
    elif (mylist[i]>1) and (mylist[i]<2):
            result=2
    elif mylist[i]==3:
            result=3
.........................
a.append(result)
print(a)
```

then show me  error :
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Comment: is the my first list with many values

Comment: Was asking more of what type of list, such as list of int/strings/bools.

Answer (score 1):

For the first code (which is different to the second), you have to put the `append` into the `for` loop so it appends the result to the list `a` on each iteration and not just at the end of the loop.

```
for i in mylist:
    if i == 1:
            result = 1
    elif i > 1 and i < 2:
            result = 2
    elif i == 3:
            result = 3
    a.append(result)
```

Remember indentation is extremely significant in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The for in loop sets I to the first value of mylist then the second and so on. You are trying to index with whatever the value of mylist[i] is so you are basically doing mylist[mylist[i]]. Try this instead.

```
for i in (mylist):
    if i==1:
        result=1
    elif (i>1) and (i<2):
        result=2
    elif i==3:
        result=3

   a.append(result)
   print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward I think. Because you are allowing floating point values to populate your mylist, when you iterate over it and use the value as an index for your mylist it is failing because as the error says, you cannot use a float as an index value. Cast the value to an integer using int(i):

```
for i in (mylist):
    i = int(i)
    if mylist[i]==1:
            result=1
    elif (mylist[i]>1) and (mylist[i]<2):
            result=2
    elif mylist[i]==3:
            result=3
```

EDIT: To show you a better way to iterate using the indices as the i variable use `for i in range(len(mylist)):` instead. I htink this is what you are actually trying to do rather than retrieve the actual values